# Не работает модуль 'keyboard' и 'pynput' (Python, OS X Ventura 13.0.1)

Tags: python, macos, pynput, python-keyboard

Всем привет, при работе с модулем `pynput.keyboard` при использовании выдает warning:

> Expected type 'str | Key | KeyCode', got 'int' instead.

Соответственно, ничего не происходит.

При попытке использования другого модуля (`keyboard`) при использовании команды в консоли `keyboard.write('Hello')` так же ничего не пишет. Читал о том, что модули не очень хорошо работают на этой ОС, однако грешу на то, что нет определенных разрешений. Всплыло один раз окно о запросе разрешения, не успел прожать так как код выполнялся. И теперь не могу понять, что делать.

Читал на хабре про модули, вот что было написано там:

> Примечание: Для MacOS вам, возможно, придется разрешить терминалу или другим приложениям изменять состояние вашей машины, например, путем ввода текста. Также имейте в виду, что по состоянию на сентябрь 2021 года библиотека все еще находится в экспериментальном состоянии на MacOS.

Как разрешить терминалу или другим приложениям изменять состояние машины? Или есть какие то альтернативные пути запустить у себя? Потому что давал на тест знакомому, у него `Windows`, все работает.

```py
import pywhatkit
import time
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(phone_no='+79037721711', message=str('Hello, my dear!'), tab_close=True)
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.click()
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
print('message sent!')
```

Comment: Ну судя по ошибке у вас какой-то аргумент в функции является целым числом (судя по всему `Key.enter`), он похоже, что не имплементирует интерфейс `KeyCode` или `Key`, попробуйте его (`Key.enter`) перевести в тип строки (т.к. похоже, что строка тоже принимается в качестве аргумента).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
import pywhatkit
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pywhatkit import sendwhatmsg

keyboard = Controller()
sendwhatmsg(to='+79037721711', message='Hello, my dear!', hour=22, minute=50)
time.sleep(5)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
print('message sent!')
```

У меня был похожий код, просто вписал ваши данные